# git ignore parameters order in xml row?

Tags: git, git-diff

Those two rows are the same, except for the parameters order:

```
 <page size="1024,768" class="PageWgt" file="home" type="normal" name="HOME"/>
 <page type="normal" name="HOME" file="home" class="PageWgt" size="1024,768"/>
```

Anyway to tell to **git diff** to consider those the same instead of show them as changed.

Thanks, BR

Comment: If they are not the same then git can't treat them as the same. You *could* automatically format the XML to some standardized parameter order in some git hook or maybe using smudge/clean filters.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, main problem it's I don't know the rigth order, but basically what you suggest mean: edit the code, trigger a "filter" that will override the code to sort the parameters to the right order?

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered pre-commit, with this custom check can be made with a simple:

```
pip install pre-commit
# create file .pre-commit-config.yaml: 

# https://pre-commit.com/
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v4.4.0  # Use the ref you want to point at
    hooks:
    -   id: check-xml
        types: [file]  # override `types: [json]`
        files: \.(jmx|xml)$

git add .pre-commit-config.yaml 
git add filetobechecked
git commit -m "checked with precommit"
```

But afaik attributes order is insignificant for xml, but not for git, may ask what can it be the best way to check if attributes values are changed since last commit?